# How to force pivotTable.js orientation

Tags: javascript, pivottable.js

I'm working with `pivotTable.js` and this is working well until i put multiple `rowData`, the `pivotTable` change the orientation.
What i have is this see

**pic 1**

[image]

and i want to force pivotTable to render this orientation: see

**pic 2**

[image]

Is there any solution to make it working correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, set the `unusedAttrsVertical` parameter to `false`. See for full parameter docs: https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/wiki/Parameters